# Incorrect Date Format in JavaScript using getMonth() and getYear()

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble understanding why a Date in Javascript come out wrong. For example...

```
$scope.campaign.date_start = new Date(19/11/2014);
Wed Nov 19 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT) - correct
$scope.campaign.date_start.getDay() = 19 - correct
```

So far so good, however getting the Month and the year gives me incorrect values....

```
$scope.campaign.date_start.getMonth() = 10 - incorrect should be 11
$scope.campaign.date_start.getYear() = 114 incorrect should be 2014
```

What I'm I going wrong here?

Comment: The months and day of the week are indexed at 0

Comment: They are *not* giving you incorrect values.  See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).  [`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth): Returns the month (0-11) [`getYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear): Returns the year minus 1900

Comment: The real question is: "What **didn't** you do?". You did not read the proverbial manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript `getMonth()` will always return actual `month-1`.  For the year, you will need to use `getFullYear()` to get the 4 digit year

Answer (score 4):

[`getMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) is 0 based, so you need to +1 to get the number of the current month.

[`getYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) is deprecated, and may break at some point in future, it (generally) returns the number of years since 1900.  The correct method to use is [`getFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear)

Answer (score 1):

`Date.getMonth()` is 0-base (January is month 0).

`Date.getYear()` is deprecated and is years since 1900 (hence 114).

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: getYear() is not 0 base, it based of a 1900, so 2014-1900 so he's getting 114

Comment: Good point. Corrected. That's what I get for typing quickly and carelessly.

Answer (score 1):

[`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) is zero-based. So you will need `getMonth()+1`

[`getYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) was not Y2K compliant, so a new function [`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) was created to return 4-digit years.